# Searching for a 80s/90s alien sci-fi (tv?) movie inspired by Lonnie Zamora incident

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I am looking for a probably 80s or 90s sci-fi movie or TV series inspired by the Lonnie Zamora incident, also refers to Socorro ufo landing.

I watched part of the movie in the 90s as I was a child.

I remember a scene where a cop chases a suspect at night on a highway in the desert hills and then suddenly got blinded by white blueish lights. The police car was looking like a ford from 70s or 80s if I recall it right. Next the officer stopped and looks down a valley where a white spacecraft stands. He shouts with his megaphone/bullhorn at two white alien beings which right away get inside their craft and fly away.

The whole scenery was looking much newer than the original incident which supposedly did happen in 1964.

The next day the officer gets back to the landing site with other police men or the press to discover burning signs on the ground and the officer tells them he also saw a sign on the door of the craft.

If I remember it right further in the movie there is also a scene inside a prison, where a prisoner got some french fries an bun to eat from a men and inside the bun is a scorpion like creature or a bug and the prisoner evetually dies eating it.

Don't know what movie that could be.

Maybe you guys have an idea!

Thanks!

Comment: sounds a bit like Fire in the Sky but some other plot points do not match

Comment: It does sound like "Fire In The Sky", but the bit about the cop seeing a UFO on the ground with two 'aliens' nearby sounds like a supposedly true UFO incident I remember reading about. I also think I remember a movie that incorporated that incident. If the movie comes to mind I'll make an answer here.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like an episode from the series "Dark Skies".

"Hostile Convergence"

- series takes place in the late 60s
- car chase in the beginning ending with an UFO
- next morning press with the pursuing officer
- a slug filled hot-dog given to a guy in prison

Comment: That's it! Never thought it is that old and from a series. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Querist You seem to have lost access to the account you used to ask this question, but you can merge your two accounts by [following the instructions here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Once you've done that, you can 'accept' this answer by clicking the checkmark on the left - a way of giving an extra thank-you to the person who solved your problem.